Should I add an interesting conculsion from my research to wikipedia?
The stated phrase in the title is a bit  negatively misguided. For context: in my amateur research, I have come upon the conclusion that
$$SNF(A \times B) =  SNF(A)\times SNF(B)$$
Where SNF(X) denotes the smith normal form of the matrix $X$. This when looked at below surface level might seem quite obvious when investigated, but for me was not a natural triviality. In addition to the fact that I haven't found any mention of it online, is it useful to publish somewhere? It would at most be an identity. The website that naturally came to mind for open collection of such knowledge was wikipedia.
Additionally, would that be an overstep on my own part, since they do not want  private reasearchers to publish?

Wikipedia explicitly bans original research: policy page. Doing so may get your content deleted. However if the result is very trivial, such as a simple calculation, mentioning it does no harm.
You can publish your results elsewhere, and then add the result, referencing your publication.
